# Autoupdating Field Based on two <select> values

Tags: javascript, html, select

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ETYgD/112/

I'm sure it will be easier to explain my problem than what I'm about to say:

So I have two  fields in an HTML form with a simple text input.  I want the text input to automatically update when the select is changed.  I tried a couple different methods, but I can't seem to get it to work.  The link above is the way I think will work the easiest.

```js
window.update = function() {
  var likelihood = document.getElementById('likelihood'),
      impact = document.getElementById('impact'),
   final = document.getElementById('final');
   if  (isNaN(likelihood))
   {
    return;
   }
   if  (isNaN(impact))
   {
    return;
   }

  final.value = parseInt(likelihood.value) * parseInt(impact.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="final" type="text"/>
<br><b>Likelihood</b><br>
<select id="likelihood" onchange="update();" />
     <option value="na">Not Available</option>
        <option value="5">Very High</option>
        <option value="4">High</option>
        <option value="3">Moderate</option>
        <option value="2">Low</option>
        <option value="1">Very Low</option>
        <option value="0">None</option>
</select>
    <br><b>Impact</b><br>
    <select id="impact" onchange="update();" />
     <option value="na">Not Available</option>
        <option value="5">Very High</option>
        <option value="4">High</option>
        <option value="3">Moderate</option>
        <option value="2">Low</option>
        <option value="1">Very Low</option>
        <option value="0">None</option>
</select>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Both `likelihood` and `impact` vars contain the HTML element. You only need to get the `value` when you are checking if they are a number.

```
window.update = function() {
  var likelihood = document.getElementById('likelihood'),
      impact = document.getElementById('impact'),
      final = document.getElementById('final');
      if  (isNaN(likelihood.value))
      {
          return;
      }
      if  (isNaN(impact.value))
      {
          return;
      }

  final.value = parseInt(likelihood.value) * parseInt(impact.value);
}
```

Your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETYgD/113/) updated.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  This helped me so much!  I only started getting into Javascript last night :P

Answer (score 0):

Your NaN function was messing something up. Here's a more jquery way of doing things:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    var likelihood = $('#likelihood');
    var impact = $('#impact');
    var final = $('#final');
    var answer = parseInt(likelihood.val()) * parseInt(impact.val());
    if ($.isNumeric(answer))
    {
        final.val(answer);        
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="final" type="text" />
<br><b>Likelihood</b>

<br>
<select id="likelihood" />
<option value="na">Not Available</option>
<option value="5">Very High</option>
<option value="4">High</option>
<option value="3">Moderate</option>
<option value="2">Low</option>
<option value="1">Very Low</option>
<option value="0">None</option>
</select>
<br><b>Impact</b>

<br>
<select id="impact" />
<option value="na">Not Available</option>
<option value="5">Very High</option>
<option value="4">High</option>
<option value="3">Moderate</option>
<option value="2">Low</option>
<option value="1">Very Low</option>
<option value="0">None</option>
</select>
```